# Github desktop не синхронизируется и лагает

Tags: git, github

Я установил Github Desktop (1). Всё хорошо работало. Я решил установить его на ещё одном компьютере (2), авторизовался под тем же аккаунтом. Я клонировал пару репозиториев к себе на вторую машину (2). Ничего не пушил. На первой машине (1), где мне необходимо часто пушить у меня больше нет возможности это делать.

Когда я нажимаю Sync прогресс-бар пару минут идёт к середине, и ещё через минуту говорит синхронизация не удалась: `Sync failed. The repository doesn`t seem to exist anymore. You may not have access, or it may have been deleted or renamed`.

Доступ к репозиторию я имею, ключ приложение само добавляет в https://github.com/settings/keys. Поэтому я не вижу причин заявлять, что у меня нет доступа или что-то там переименовано.

Я попробовал logout и зайти заново — сгенерировал таким образом уже два десятка ssh-ключей, но результат тот же.

Тогда я открыл Git shell встроенный в приложение. Ввожу git pull и получаю:

```
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,192.30.253.113' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
```

Я пробовал все эти `ssh-keygen -R <hostname>`. Пробовал удалять know_hosts (его я создавал, когда пользовался git-scm.

Видимо, вся суть не в этом. Что сделать, чтоб заставить авторизовываться Github Desktop на Github?

На всякий случай выложу `ssh -v git@github.com`

```
OpenSSH_7.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2j  26 Sep 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 5: Applying options for github.com
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.253.112] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/higimo/.ssh/github_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/higimo/.ssh/github_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version libssh-0.7.0
debug1: no match: libssh-0.7.0
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit
> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit
> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:....................
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,192.30.253.112' (RSA) to the list ofknow
n hosts.
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
```

Ну и вторая проблема, которая обнаружилась. Мне было не очень критично пушить через приложение Desktop, я запускал в консоли команду. Но сейчас после одного коммита я подготавливаю второй в течении 10 минут (если сразу сделать, то ошибка не воспроизводится) и когда нажимаю кнопку Commit, то приложение падает в «вечную загрузку».

Comment: Если в командной строке работает, а в гитхабоклиенте нет, есть смысл написать им баг-репорт.

Comment: @D-side в шеле, поставляемом с git-scm работает. В шеле поставляемом с Github Desktop не работает.

Comment: Тогда, по всей видимости, баг в Github for Windows. Пишите в саппорт.

Comment: @D-side так там нет ссылки на issue, проект-то закрытый. https://github.com/desktop/

Comment: Так поддержка гитхаба-то не там :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не знаю точно, что повлияло, но я переустановил приложение, перезашёл в аккаунт, удалил старые, не использованные ключи и перезагрузился. Теперь не показывает проблем с синхронизацией и не падает после пары минут простоя.